# finding time slots present between start time and end time in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

We have csv file containing predefined time slots.
According to start time and end time provided by the user we want time slots present between the start time and end time.

eg

```
start time =11:00:00
end time=19:00:00

output- slot_no 2,3,4,5
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `loc` and [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) for selecting column `Slot_no`, all columns and values are converted [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html), also `midnight` is replaced to `24:00:00`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'Slot_no':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
'start_time':['0:01:00','8:01:00','10:01:01','12:01:00','14:01:00','18:01:01','20:01:00'],
'end_time':['8:00:00','10:00:00','12:00:00','14:00:00','18:00:00','20:00:00','0:00:00']})
df = df.reindex_axis(['Slot_no','start_time','end_time'], axis=1)                 
df['start_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['start_time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['end_time'].replace('0:00:00', '24:00:00'))
print (df)
   Slot_no  start_time        end_time
0        1    00:01:00 0 days 08:00:00
1        2    08:01:00 0 days 10:00:00
2        3    10:01:01 0 days 12:00:00
3        4    12:01:00 0 days 14:00:00
4        5    14:01:00 0 days 18:00:00
5        6    18:01:01 0 days 20:00:00
6        7    20:01:00 1 days 00:00:00
```

---

```
start = pd.to_timedelta('11:00:00')
end = pd.to_timedelta('19:00:00')

mask = df['start_time'].between(start, end) | df['end_time'].between(start, end)

s = df.loc[mask, 'Slot_no']
print (s)
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
Name: Slot_no, dtype: int64

L = df.loc[mask, 'Slot_no'].tolist()
print (L)
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thank you .Your code was helpful.But for start time=11:00:00  we want time slot no 3 and for end time=19:00:00 slot no 7.Help with this we are novice in python .@jezrael

Comment: Do you thonk add `=` like `s = df.loc[(df['start_time'] >= start) & (df['end_time'] <= end), 'Slot_no']` ?

Comment: The edited answer gives correct output for start time=11:00:00.But doesn't give output for end time =19:00:00 as slot no 7.Please help with this.@jezrael

Comment: But  why slot `7` ? It is betwen `20:01:00` and `00:00:00`, so no match.